# Why do my stopwatches keep stopping?

Tags: vb.net, reset, stopwatch

Hey this is my first post so sorry if it's poorly explained .~.

So I'm working in VB.Net and in this block of code, I'm trying to get 2 timers to start when a key is pressed:

- The 1st (shorter) one displays an image until 750 milliseconds have
  elapsed, at which point the image disappears and the 1st timer resets
  itself
- The 2nd timer prevents any other key presses being accepted for 1000 milliseconds, after which it resets itself. Sort of like this:

  ```
  If sw2 is not running
      Select Case Check if arrow keys are pressed
          Start sw1 and sw2
      End Select
  EndIf

  If sw1.totalmilliseconds >= 750 then
      Reset sw1
  EndIf

  If sw2.totalmilliseconds >= 1000 then
      Reset sw2
  EndIf
  ```

But what actually happens is while I'm holding the key down, the timers constantly restart themselves and as soon I let go of the key, they reset themselves back to nothing.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Are they declared in the event? Can you post a bit more code?

Comment: Oh
My
God.

Yep, I declared them in the same procedure and as soon as I moved them, it was fine ;u; Thank you, I feel stupid now

Comment: Welcome to the stupid club =D